# App showing unwanted ads even after restricting background data

Tags: ads

I installed a game, and I am getting some unwanted advertisements despite already [restricting background data](http://www.technipages.com/android-enable-disable-background-data) for that app.

These advertisements do have a cancel button, but that does not work. I have to click on them forcefully and they will download something. After that, it will display a page with the application details and option "OK" and "Cancel". On canceling further, the ad dismisses.

In the end, I uninstalled the game, but is there any way to cancel such advertisement or completely block them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are what is called "Push Ads", they are coming from an app you installed, most likely a "free" game... Install [Add-ons Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.denper.addonsdetector) and look at what apps are using push ads and remove them. I would also post a review in the app store the app was from stating the app uses push ads for the benefit of others.